# Hacer un Backup de la BD en DigitalOcean en un momento especifico (usando la API)

Tags: laravel, digitalocean

Estoy usando Laravel para mi sitio, la idea es crear un comando de Laravel que lo que haga en una peticion a la API de DigitalOcean, o sea, la idea es que cada vez que se ejecute ese comando, se haga un backup de mi base de datos. (No quiero programar un backup diario o semanal, quiero hacerlos puntualmente).

No encuentro nada al respecto:

https://simplebackups.com/

https://docs.digitalocean.com/reference/api/api-reference/#operation/dropletActions_list